# Laravel relative paths not working as expected on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-blade, relative-url

I'm just using Mac OS's native apache2 server for my localhost. In my httpd.conf file, I set

`DocumentRoot "/Users/user_name/Local Sites/"`

...that directory houses all my sites I work on locally:

```
Users
 -user_name
  --Local Sites
   ---site_1
   ---site_2
   ---site_3
   ---site_4
```

So, for my particular Laravel project for `site_1`, I set the following in .env:

`APP_URL=http://localhost/site_1`

...and again in `config/app.php`:

`'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/site_1'),`

However, when I try to use one of Laravel's relative path builders, it includes the whole path *above* what I had defined as my document's root and server's localhost. For example:

```
public_path() = /Users/user_name/Local Sites/site_1/public
```

The problem, then, is that when I use that variable to, say, link to a .js file in `public/js`, the generated path is

`http://localhost/Users/user_name/Local%20Sites/site_1/public`

...which is invalid, of course, because the proper path is really

`http://localhost/site_1/public`

**I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I'm too stupid to figure out what it is!** My site works when I resolve those paths explicitly, but then of course everything breaks when I publish to my web host (with absolute instead of relative paths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not mix the use of the helper function publich_path() and assets().

You should link your JS/CSS/Img the following way:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/main.js')}}"/>
```

Laravel will translate that call into

```
<script src="http://localhost/site_1/js/main.js"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can you explain a bit more, though? As I thought this scenario was literally what the helper functions were for...

Comment: Also, is there a way to resolve paths in Javascript so I can keep those relative as well? Example: I load some JSON files in my global nav js file, which is one level above most of my blade files, but breaks on a page that is 2 levels deep (because that file would require `../` instead of `./`).